# Which Java classes are usable when developing native Apps in Android?

Tags: java, android

It's said in the title. which Java Classes can I use when developing Android apps. Are there any exceptions, can I use the lot of the Java Library, like the whole of the standard Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost use all the Java Classes. The only thing you need to be aware of is that you can't use any Graphical and UI classes as Swing and AWT. Else it's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use all classes listed in [the Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) for your desired API level (which corresponds to Android releases).

The Android API is *roughly* based on the Java SE API, but it is missing a few parts and has added significant parts of its own API.

Knowing the Java SE API can certainly help, but you shouldn't assume that everything in there is available on Android.