# Unable to resolve superclass of External Library

Tags: java, android

I am new to both ANDROID & JAVA.And I am final year electrical engineer student.But I have a little knowledge of programming.My project is to create an APPLICATION for electrical oriented problems that is Electrical come Mathematical Sums.For this purpose I used External Library called `FLANAGAN.JAR`.Initially I have finished my JAVA program for a single sum named `Formation of ADMITTANCE BUS Matrix`.Then I finished my APP'S UI. Actually this was done for 70%(For output I didnt make still).

Now what my problem is when I implemented my JAVA Program for creating Android app I used LogCat to see my output.There I found these statements...But I got my output..Anyhow I want to know what does these statements mean??

```
02-25 19:31:01.263: W/dalvikvm(616): Unable to resolve superclass of Lflanagan/plot/Plot; (909)
02-25 19:31:01.263: W/dalvikvm(616): Link of class 'Lflanagan/plot/Plot;' failed
02-25 19:31:01.263: W/dalvikvm(616): Unable to resolve superclass of Lflanagan/plot/PlotGraph; (903)
02-25 19:31:01.263: W/dalvikvm(616): Link of class 'Lflanagan/plot/PlotGraph;' failed
02-25 19:31:01.263: E/dalvikvm(616): Could not find class 'flanagan.plot.PlotGraph', referenced from method flanagan.math.ArrayMaths.plot
02-25 19:31:01.263: W/dalvikvm(616): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 904 (Lflanagan/plot/PlotGraph;) in Lflanagan/math/ArrayMaths;
02-25 19:31:01.263: D/dalvikvm(616): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0037
02-25 19:31:01.501: W/dalvikvm(616): Unable to resolve superclass of Lflanagan/plot/Plot; (909)
02-25 19:31:01.501: W/dalvikvm(616): Link of class 'Lflanagan/plot/Plot;' failed
02-25 19:31:01.501: W/dalvikvm(616): Unable to resolve superclass of Lflanagan/plot/PlotGraph; (903)
02-25 19:31:01.511: W/dalvikvm(616): Link of class 'Lflanagan/plot/PlotGraph;' failed
02-25 19:31:01.511: D/dalvikvm(616): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2ee9 at 0x39 in Lflanagan/math/ArrayMaths;.plot
```

I got output also :

```
02-25 19:31:01.620: I/System.out(616): The Admittance Bus of given data is : 
02-25 19:31:01.632: I/System.out(616): 0.0 - j8.75  0.0 + j1.25  0.0 + j2.5  
02-25 19:31:01.640: I/System.out(616): 0.0 + j1.25  0.0 - j6.25  0.0 + j2.5  
02-25 19:31:01.640: I/System.out(616): 0.0 + j2.5  0.0 + j2.5  0.0 - j5.0
```

Comment: Electrical student and programming project !!!! outsource it.. :PP

Comment: not sure, but may be that library is java based, and android != Java, you still need to port java library sometimes to android..

Comment: @Farhan What does outsource mean??

Comment: @Farhan I need that library for creating this app.I am in final stage.Is it possible to convert java based library to android based

Comment: told you, "m not sure".. but yes, its possible.. and i think, you said, you getting the result.. so ignore these warnings.. ;)

Comment: @Farhan All java classes are perfectly usable in an Android app. Android itself uses some built-in classes from the Java API.

Comment: @Farhan Also i got my output..See the edited

Comment: @Farhan Then how to fix this problem..Any idea?? sir

Comment: @Farhan Right now I can ignore these warnings.But later I need that class which got warnings for other sums.At that time I need to know..

Comment: @Flawyte, just for info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7413350/578215

Comment: @user3342588, have a look maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295672/updated-eclipse-adt-libgdx-doesnt-compile-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the *jar* which contains your base classes to your android project's classpath. They are generally placed in a `libs/` folder at your project folder's root.

Also, make sure that the *jar* is configured to be exported with your source code when packaging your APK. I don't know which IDE you are using, but in order to do that in Eclipse just go to your project's preferences : right click on it > *Preferences* > *Build path* > *Order and Export* and then make sure your *jar* is checked.

Comment: ya my library is checked

Comment: Try to change the order by placing it upper in the list.

Comment: yeah just now tried by placing it first...Same problem

Comment: Don't place it first, external jars should always remain lower than Java & android libraries. But whatever, I think you problem doesn't come from that.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure that your external jar files are inside a "libs" folder within the Android project. The folder MUST be called "libs". This page will probably be helpful to you.

http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: yeah its there.It also got checked in Build path